# Confused with the alias solution?

Tags: alias, ls, prompt

I am trying to define alias for a group of commands counting recursively and displaying the number of all sub-directories encountered for any working directory (including ones with invisible file names). So far what I have done is:

```
ls -R | wc -l
```

But it does not display the hidden files number. So I tried this command:

```
ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l
```

But I am not sure whether it is the right command or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** parse the output of `ls`. See some explanations here:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

As others recommended, use `find` instead. And the best way (even when you have directory names  that contain  newlines  or other  types of white space) would be:

```
alias countdir='find . -type d -print0 | tr -dc "\\0" | wc -c'
```

See `man find`, `man tr`, `man wc` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is `find . -type d|wc -l` a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `find` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html)) to do the searching. As an example,

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`

will print the number of all directories in the current working directory.

The `-maxdepth` option controls how far `find` will descend into the directories. With a value of `1`, it will just use the current directory and list its subdirectories. With `2`, it will list the subdirectories' subdirectories, too, and so on.

This has just a single, small drawback: `find` includes `.` (the current working directory) in its listing, thus the number returned by `wc -l` will be off by one.