# Confusion regarding sub-directories?

Tags: command-line, prompt

I have a question to `count` and display `number` of `sub-directories` including hidden ones(`invisible sub-directories`) recursively. I can display sub-directories recursively but I am confused with the invisible sub-directories. In addition I can only use `ls` and `wc` command for the solution. Please don't suggest `'find'` command I have to use only `ls` and `wc` command.

So far I have tried the following commands.

```
ls -1 | wc -l

ls -R | wc -l

ls -R | wc -c

ls -aR | wc -l

ls -aR | wc -c
```

But still I have not found the solution. Can you please enlighten me.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Nope my friend gave it and I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ls -lAR | grep '^d' | wc -l
```

But you should keep in mind: [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! In this case is better to use `find` as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/376850/147044).

See also `man ls` to understand why I used `-l`, `-A` and `-R` options.

Comment: can you please give some examples regarding invisible sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

I just re-read the questions and noticed that it does not want to use find.

I found two that appear to both give the correct answer:

The first is:

```
ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l
```

The second is:

```
ls -Rp | grep "/$" | wc -l
```

Comment: Please read the question properly. I know using find command is best for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience `find` is a better tool to search files or directories – especially recursively and including dot file names.

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

You can optimize a little, if you only write and count single characters for each match:

```
expr $(find -mindepth 1 -type d -printf 1 | wc -c) - 1
```

If you want to include the working directory into the result, set `-mindepth` to 0 (or omit it).

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the OP only wants to use `ls` and `wc`.

Comment: I know it and I am very fond of 'find' command but I need the answer using ls and wc command

Comment: Ah yes. Hence the comment asking, if this is a class assignment.